# Apache htaccess rewrite rule not matching

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am attempting to match a URL like

```
http://www.example.org/?h=b1c60d1bf7c7119fef9fc726068e1418166.xml
```

or

```
?h=b1c60d1bf7c7119fef9fc726068e1418166.jsonp&callback=testing
```

and re-write it like this:

```
?h=b1c60d1bf7c7119fef9fc726068e1418166&output=true&format=true&data_type=xml
```

or

```
?h=b1c60d1bf7c7119fef9fc726068e1418166&output=true&format=true&data_type=jsonp&callback=testing
```

Here is the .htaccess file with the regex I came up with.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/?\?h=([a-z0-9]+)\.(xml|json|jsonp|rss)(\&callback=[a-z_0-9]+)?$ ?h=$1&output=true&format=true&data_type=$2&callback=$3 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Any ideas why this isn't matching? I've tested this in the server environment and on http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RewriteRule` does not match query, just path an file/directory name.

Use `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}` to work with query.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get this working on the test, now I need to figure out why I'm getting a 500.  RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} h=([a-zA-Z0-9]*)\.(xml|jsonp|json|rss)(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/? /?h=%1&data_type=%2&output=true&format=true%3 [L,NC,QSA]